# Добавить в друзья

Tags: php, mysql

Как реализовать функцию "Добавить в друзья" на PHP? Схему просто накидайте!

Comment: Автор, у тебя вообще голова работает?
Ты просишь готовый вариант, и при этом говоришь, что "гугл не предлагать"
Подумай головой и всё получится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала продумай структуру таблиц, очевидно что должно быть две таблицы, одна с юзерами, 2-ая с друзьями. Многие ко многим это называется. Создаешь их, а в пхп потом просто берешь в таблицу с друзьями и добавляешь ид_юзера и ид_друга. Ид_друга это тот же ид_юзера из таблицы с юзерами.

1-ая Таблица с юзерами:

```
`users` `id` `name`
```

2-ая Таблица связь с друзьями (я исп. многие ко многим):

```
`friends` `user_id` `friend_id`
```

Теперь `friend_id` это `id`-шник любого юзера из 1-ой таблицы.

А в `php` делов-то. Напр.

```
// берем ид-шник по имени поль-я
$UserId = getUserIdByName($UserName);

// берем ид-друга, так же само по его имени,
$FriendId = getUserIdByName($FriendName);

// Добавляем в таблицу friends связь
function AddToFriend( $UserId, $FriendId );
```

Представим что у нас есть в таблице с юзерами два юзера `Вася`[2] и `Петя`[3], ну и собственно вы [1] там тоже должны быть, т.е. 3 человека.

И поступаем далее как я описал выше, сначала берем свой id, затем id, допустим `Васи`, и добавляем их в таблицу Друзья (`friends`). Что в итоге?

В итоге вы должны получить примерно следующее в таблице `friends`

```
`user_id` | `friend_id`
    1     |      2
```

Чтобы добавить `Петю`, поступаем точно так же, бере ид-шники друг-друга и добавляем в табицу с друзьями, в итоге получится уже такой набор данных:

```
`user_id` | `friend_id`
    1     |      2
    1     |      3
```

Красиво получилось? А теперь очень легко выбрать друзей по своему `id`-шнику, но вы сначала это сделайте.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всегда бы так !:) Вот у меня толко ещё одна проблема есть

http://hashcode.ru/questions/147821/php-вывод-только-последних

И да , так подробно расписывать не нужно я и в первом ответе всё прекрасно понял :)

Answer (score 0):

Схема простая: добавляешь таблицу в базе: friends с полями  id, user_id, friend_id
Потом просто записываешь сюда нужных людей

Comment: Всё, что мне надо было, спасибо большое! Неужели так сложно было?